# Platform-independent OpenSSL library

Tags: c++, cross-platform, platform-independent

I'm in the process of writing a program in C++ which needs to compile and run... anywhere. It can be run from Linux, MacOS, Windows, DOS, OS/2, BSD, hell, even custom written operating system that has a C++ compiler if need be.

One thing that I have gotten extremely stuck on, is OpenSSL. The program makes heavy use of public key infrastructure. It needs to generate keypairs, encrypt, decrypt, sign and verify. On linux, I can be "pretty" sure that openssl exists, that's not the problem. I can't be so sure on windows and other platforms and I want the executable to be alone.

So, what I need is a library that provides a "zero hassle" compilation in any ISO-compliant C++ compiler. I have found a few which VS compiler cannot compile (and by the looks of it, debugging them would be hell).

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried statically linking libssl?

Comment: Hmm I haven't actually attempted that no... will try. However, it would only solve it on Windows platform, as compiling on other platforms would still cause a lack of OpenSSL...

Comment: Have you simply tried to built OpenSSL from source for those platforms where it doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The openssl library is a C library and if VS is not able to compile C code. Well it's  not the library to  blame then. I've seen a lot of code written against the openSSL. I'm just realy suprised how poor the documentation about this system really is.

The OpenSSL homepage is here:
http://www.openssl.org/